# Export word with Print Layout from .mhtml in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, export

I am exporting a word document with images which is converted from .mhtml file.
I referred the below link for exporting the word.

http://www.revium.com.au/articles/sandbox/aspnet-mvc-convert-view-to-word-document/

Now the word is getting exported but its in web layout. But I need the document in Print Layout.

Can anyone help me solving this issue.

**Edited**

I solved the issue with the help of below link

http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/open-ms-word-documents-print-layout-view-57860.html

You can always reverse engineer it. Open your doc in word. Do it up the way you want it and Save it as html. Open with a text editor and use what you need.

That is what i do.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 9">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 9">
<title></title>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:DocumentProperties>
 </o:DocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Print</w:View>
 </w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
```

I also added some extra code generated by my word then only I got it correctly.

Hope this will help someone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Write the file to the response base, get the bytes from the stream and try that. It should force a download of the file

```
 HttpResponseBase.OutputStream(fileBytes,0,fileBytes.GetLength(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Its showing the following error 'Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpResponseBase.OutputStream' cannot be used like a method' How to use the above code.